# Java in operator

Tags: java, syntactic-sugar, jls, in-operator

For the one millionth time, I would have liked to use an `IN` operator in Java, similar to the `IN` operator in SQL. It could just be implemented as compiler syntactic sugar. So this

```
if (value in (a, b, c)) {
}
else if (value in (d, e)) {
}
```

...would really be awesome. In fact, the above is the same as the rather verbose (and not adapted for primitives) construct here:

```
if (Arrays.asList(a, b, c).contains(value)) {
}
else if (Arrays.asList(d, e).contains(value)) {
}
```

Or like this for `int`, `long` and similar types:

```
switch (value) {
  case a:
  case b:
  case c:
    // ..
    break;

  case d:
  case e:
    // ..
    break;
 }
```

Or maybe there could be even more efficient implementations.

#### Question:

Is something like this going to be part of Java 8? How can I make such a suggestion, if not? Or is there any equivalent construct that I could use right now?

Comment: I think Guava should contain something equal.

Comment: You have this in Groovy, which is like a Java++ :)

Comment: @Kico Lobo: Nice to know. Unfortunately, I can't use Groovy :-/

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut: Do you have a pointer? The Guava library is quite big...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [op4j](http://www.op4j.org/):

```
Op.onListFor(a,b,c).get().contains(value);
```

Using the same approach, you could create a helper classes `Is` with a method `in`:

```
class Is<T> {
    private T value;

    public Is( T value ) { this.value = value; }

    public boolean in( T... set ) {
        for( T item : set ) {
            if( value.equals( item ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static <T> Is<T> is( T value ) {
        return new Is<T>( value );
    }
}
```

with a static import, you can write:

```
if(is(value).in(a,b,c)) {
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I was just going to ask if there is a library for precisely this kind of DSL!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Funny, how Op4j is hardly used, though. When you compare the downloads with those of [Lambda-J](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj), for instance

Comment: Yeah, it's one of these gems that sit in a browser tab, begging to be used but somehow, there never is the time to start with it...

Comment: I've added a feature request to add your suggested `Is` class to the library. `Are` might be a good class as well for `if (are(val1, val2).allIn(a, b, c))`: https://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/op4j/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=15

Answer (score 21):

You can write a helper method to do it.

```
public static <T> boolean isIn(T t, T... ts) {
    for(T t2: ts) 
      if (t.equals(t2)) return true;
    return false;
}

// later
if (isIn(value, a,b,c)) {

} else if (isIn(value, d,e)) {

}
```

Comment: True, that's the simplest workaround. I guess that `isIn` method could also be found in Guava, some place...

Comment: Nice to see, there's actually a library for that kind of helper methods. See the newly accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

There has been a very old proposal for [collection literals](https://docs.google.com/Doc?id=ddv8ts74_4cbnn5mhj&pli=1).

Currently there is [`Sets.newHashSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet%28E...%29) in Guava which is pretty similar to `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: I was sure that I had seen something like this before. So it's not part of project coin, neither for Java 8... But with this, I could write `[a, b, c].contains(value)`. That would be acceptable. So the Guava solution wouldn't be less verbose. I think the overhead of a `HashSet` for a constant, low number of elements is not worth the trouble, compared to `Arrays.asList()`...

Comment: The performance should be similar for both collection types for small sizes. The problem is that it is created every time it is used, though hotspot will probably optimize it. With collection literals containing literals that becomes trivial.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the [Java Community Process](http://jcp.org/en/home/index)

Comment: Thanks, I know JCP. I also know the [coin-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/coin-dev) mailing list. How can I increase chances of being heard?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt something like an IN operator would be made available, as there are already multiple ways of doing this(like using switch) as you yourself pointed out.

And I think requirement list for project-coin and J8 is already fully loaded to be anything like this to be considered.

Comment: That's what I feared (J8 being already fully loaded). But currently, there is nothing as neat as a simple `IN` operator to actually do what an `IN` operator does. The switch is horribly verbose. `Arrays.asList(...)` contains might be an option

Comment: you're right. Probably, my suggestion would go too far. I'd prefer Hermal's reference to Joshua Bloch's proposition of having collection literals...

Comment: @Suraj Chandran: I agree: a language should not support too many programming idioms, even it that makes the code shorter, it makes the language and the compiler more complex.